# putting this line into excel.Formula "=IF(C4 = "x";1;0)" isnt working because of double `" "`

Tags: c#, string, excel

I want to put this line into a excel cell with c# : `=IF(C4 = "x";1;0)`

But when I type: .Formula = `"=IF(C4 = "x";1;0)"`, it cuts the sentence into 2 seperate parts, because of the double `"`, any idea how to fix this?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the escape characters `\"` This will read the `"` as a string

Answer (score 1):

Excel uses commas to separate parameters, not semicolons.

Escape the quotes with a backslash `\`.

Change it to this: `"=IF(C4=\"x\",1,0)"`

Answer (score 1):

You could escape each individual character, using the escape character `\`:

`range.Forumula = "=IF(C4 = \"x\",1,0);"`

Alternatively, you can denote the block as a string literal by adding the `@` character before your string:

`range.Formula = @"=IF(C4 = "x",1,0)";`

Just be careful with using string literals, as they will disable the escaping of characters all together:

`Console.WriteLine("Hello,\tWorld"); //prints: Hello,    World`

`Console.WriteLine(@"Hello,\tWorld"); //prints: Hello,\tWorld`

More information on string literals: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

One more note, Excel uses `,` to separate parameters in formulas, not `;` as you have in your example.

Comment: Omg thank you so much, because in excel i had to put `;` so seperate chars, and i couldnt figure out why it wasnt working. Gonna try the `,` when im at work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASCII character

```
    'VB.NET:
    "=IF(C4 = " & Chr(34) & "x" & Chr(34) & ",1,0)"

    'C#:
    "=IF(C4 = " + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34) + "x" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34) + ",1,0)";

    'VBA:
    "=IF(C4 = \"x\",1,0)"
```

ASCII character number 34 is double quote.

Comment: I would guess the downvote relates to you giving a solution that works in VBA when the issue is in C#. Just a wild guess.

Comment: I am guessing it was downvoted becuase that would not work in C#.  in order to have it work as you have it it would need to be "=IF(C4 = " + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34) + "x" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34) + ";1;0)";    & doesn't work to combine strings in C# you must use the + operator

Comment: Fair enough, I'll adjust for future viewers

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, excel uses either commas or semicolons depending on the system language settings of the computer it is installed on.